# Geode not allowing me to query for another region

Tags: geode

My geode client is working to persist and retrieve the data in the specific region.

```
        ClientRegionFactoryBean<Integer, Book> region =
            new ClientRegionFactoryBean<>();
    region.setName("Book");
    region.setPool(gemfirePool);
    region.setCache(cache.getObject());
    region.setShortcut(ClientRegionShortcut.PROXY);
```

however, if i am trying to use the region to query for another region, it doesn't allow me to do that:

```
org.apache.geode.cache.query.QueryInvalidException: Should not execute region.query with a different region in the from clause: Book was not present in:select * from /Staff
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You should obtain the QueryService from the ClientCache 
 i.e `clientCache.getQueryService();` rather than `region.query();`

Comment: my bad. i was keep trying to use gemfireTemplate which is created by single region to run the query. Just in case, do you know how to create gemfireTemplate, to be able to query cross region. So far, i only see one costructor of GemfireTemplate(Region)  https://docs.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/GemfireTemplate.html#GemfireTemplate-org.apache.geode.cache.Region-